# Picking data for Bokeh HoverTool output from ColumnDataSource

Tags: python, python-3.x, bokeh

I'm a bit vexed with the HoverTool in Bokeh.  I've got a ColumnDataSource that has multiple data 'columns' and I use the various columns to plot lines on a graph.  When I hover on one of the points on a line, I want to show the 'x' ('rpm' data in my CDS) and 'y' (one of the other columns in my CDS) data for that point on that line.

Since all lines are using the same CDS (different columns for 'y' values), for the life of me, I can't figure out how to discriminate the 'y' value for the line being hovered on, and display only the 'y' value for that line.  Currently, I'm just displaying all of the 'y' values for the 'x' value being hovered on.

I don't want to use the '$y' parameter, because that's just the location of the cursor on the graph, not the data for the hovered point.

Would appreciate your thoughts.  Thanks.

Note, this program plots vehicle speed for given engine RPM, and each series is by transmission gear.

```
import itertools
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool
from bokeh.palettes import Category20_20 as palette

data={'rpm': range(2000, 4000, 500),
     '1st': [15.00040961597459,
             18.750512019968237,
             22.50061442396188,
             26.25071682795553],
     '2nd': [28.241511931310182,
             35.301889914137725,
             42.36226789696527,
             49.422645879792825],
     '3rd': [45.751249328722494,
             57.18906166090312,
             68.62687399308373,
             80.06468632526436],
     '4th': [66.30615844742391,
             82.8826980592799,
             99.45923767113587,
             116.03577728299183]}

cds = ColumnDataSource(data=data)

fig = figure(width=800, height= 600, title='Speed', x_axis_label='RPM', y_axis_label='Speed(mph)')
hovertools= HoverTool(tooltips=[('Gear', '$name'),
                                ('4th', '@4th{0.0}'),
                                ('3rd', '@3rd{0.0}'),
                                ('2nd', '@2nd{0.0}'),
                                ('1st', '@1st{0.0}'),
                                ('RPM', '@rpm')],)

colors = itertools.cycle(palette)
fig.add_tools(hovertools)
for gear in ('1st', '2nd', '3rd', '4th'):
    color = colors.__next__()
    fig.line(x='rpm',
             y=gear,
             source=cds,
             color=color,
             legend=gear + ' gear',
             muted_color=color,
             muted_alpha=0.2,
             line_width=1,
             name=gear + ' gear')
    fig.circle(x='rpm',
               y=gear,
               source=cds,
               color=color,
               legend=gear + ' gear',
               muted_color=color,
               muted_alpha=0.2,
               line_width=1,
               name=gear + ' gear')

fig.legend.click_policy = "mute"
fig.legend.background_fill_alpha = 0.5

show(fig)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@$name` to look up the value of the column that has `$name` as the column name:

```
hovertools= HoverTool(tooltips=[('Gear', '$name'),
                                ('data', '@$name{0.0}'),
                                ('RPM', '@rpm')],)
```

But note, for this to work, the value you set for `name` in the glyph method has to *match the column name*. E.g. I had to change:

```
for gear in ('1st', '2nd', '3rd', '4th'):
    color = colors.__next__()
    fig.line(x='rpm',
             y=gear,
             ...
             name=gear)   # CHANGED to match column name
    fig.circle(x='rpm',
               y=gear,
               ...
               name=gear) # CHANGED to match column name
```

This yields:

[image]

[image]

Note that in the "tuple" format for tooltips, the first label value is not expaned, so if you want e.g. something like `4th gear: <value>` on a per-line basis, then you'll want to use a [Custom Tooltip](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#custom-tooltip)

Comment: THANK YOU!!!  
 
That did exactly what I needed.  It's the second time I've come across this issue.  Wish there were a more intuitive and cleaner way to do that, but it gets the job done. 
 
I've been raking though the documentation and could not figure out how to get it done.  I tried something very close to that, but didn't get it to work.  The docs are a bit lacking in detail for things outside of their basic examples.  Especially for formatting.
 
Thanks again!

Comment: It is technically in this first section https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#basic-tooltips but probably easy to miss. If you are familiar with Sphinx/ReST, help improving the docs is always appreciated.

Comment: Thanks, I actually read that section several times.  Mainly lack of understanding of variable expansion (especially nested expansion e.g. '@$name{0.0}') and formatting was what was giving me trouble.

Comment: Right it's a little obscure and mostly the result of history. In general `@foo` or `@{foo}` always means reference the column called "foo". Then the "special" variable `$name` was added, which reports the name of the renderer. Then finally folks wanted to use that name, as a column name, hence we settled on `@$name`, or "use the value of $name as the column name", as a path to provide that capability within the existing conventions. But yes, it's not the most obvious thing and could be documented/explained better.